# How do I compare multiple timeseries?

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I'm working with data on litter (fallen leaves, flowers, etc) accumulating under different genera of trees. I have a year's timeseries for each genus, and I'm really more interested in comparisons among genera than trying to fit regressions to seasonality, etc. I'm thinking to use some sort of timeseries tests because subsequent measurements are not fully independent -- this is the standing stock of litter, not the flux of fresh inputs.

Data files: [all samples](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4109130/curbtest/curbtest.csv), and [average](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4109130/curbtest/curbtest_avg.csv) by genus/date. In the following plot, points are individual samples, and lines connect genus averages.
[image: Points are individual samples; lines connect genus averages]

There's enough overlap that I'm not going to try to do all pairwise comparisons. Two that are of a priori interest: Genus C is essentially a control, and as you see its litter is much less, especially in the fall. Genus E suffered an insect outbreak in the summer and dropped a lot of green leaves. I'm interested in testing if either of these is statistically significant.

I'm working in R. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I'm interested in testing if either of these is statistically significant." What exactly would you like to test? Is it genus C versus E in October, or something else?